# Using Marshal.Copy from int[][] to IntPtr gives me error

Tags: c#, c, arrays

(Sorry for my English, if it is not able to understand).

Lately I've had problems with **Marshal.Copy** function, I've been trying to **transform a two-dimensional array of int, using the format int[ , ]**.

It happens to design a function to transform this two dimensional array to another, but uses the format **int [ ][ ]**, and then I wanted to apply the function

```
Marshal.Copy (int [] source, int startIndex, IntPtr destination, int lenght)
```

and when I run my program gives me an **error** when trying to perform the transformation, because it tells me that my **argument 'destination' is null**.

The truth is that I could not find information related to the problem and need to make this transformation, because I use a dll to C, and i defined a C# structure defined as follows:

**C# Structure:**

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public struct board
{
    public int rows;
    public int columns;
    public int difficulty;
    public int boardID;
    public IntPtr sudokuArray; // int**
    public IntPtr sudokuRestrictions; // int**
}
```

**My C# function to transform:**

```
public void reverseBoard(int[,] newArray, int[,] newRestrictions)
{
    int[][] transformedArray = new int[size][];
    int[][] transformedRestrictions = new int[size][];
    IntPtr[] ptrSubNewArray = new IntPtr[size];
    IntPtr[] ptrSubNewRestrictions = new IntPtr[size];
    IntPtr ptrNewArray = new IntPtr();
    IntPtr ptrNewRestrictions = new IntPtr();

    for (int a = 0; a < size; a++)
    {
        transformedArray[a] = new int[size];
        transformedRestrictions[a] = new int[size];
    }

    for (int b = 0; b < size; b++)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
        {
            transformedArray[b][c] = newArray[b, c];
            transformedRestrictions[b][c] = newRestrictions[b, c];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        ptrSubNewArray[i] = new IntPtr();
        ptrSubNewRestrictions[i] = new IntPtr();
        // Here throws this exception, because of ptrSubNewArray[i]
        // 'System.ArgumentNullException'
        Marshal.Copy(transformedArray[i], 0, ptrSubNewArray[i], size);
        Marshal.Copy(transformedRestrictions[i], 0, ptrSubNewRestrictions[i], size);
    }

    Marshal.Copy(ptrSubNewArray, 0, ptrNewArray, size);
    Marshal.Copy(ptrSubNewRestrictions, 0, ptrNewRestrictions, size);

    actualBoard.sudokuArray = ptrNewArray;
    actualBoard.sudokuRestrictions = ptrNewRestrictions;
}
```

If somebody know how to fix this, it could be useful.
Thanks.

Comment: `new IntPtr()` isn't gonna cut it. It actually creates an empty `IntPtr`. Look into `Marshal.AllocateMemory(size)` (or something similar) to dynamically allocate memory into a managed `IntPtr`.